# How to configure nginx to redirect with subpaths matching given pattern

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy. I want to redirect locations matching some patterns keeping exactly the same subpaths. For example, this configuration does not work for me:

```
location ~ ^/bpmn/?(.*)$ {
            resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
            set $upstream activiti:8080;
            proxy_pass         http://$upstream/$1;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
```

I would like to redirect the location matches the path "/bpmn/a/b/c" to "http://$upstream/a/b/c". My configuration works only for one level (e.g. "bpmn/a").
Thanks a lot for your help,
Regards.